# overriding base class method using virtual does not work

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have 2 classes : ShapeTwoD & Square

Square is derived from ShapeTwoD

**Class ShapeTwoD**

```
class ShapeTwoD
{
public:
ShapeTwoD();
ShapeTwoD(string,bool);

string getName();
void setName(string);

bool getContainsWarpSpace();
void setContainsWarpSpace(bool);

void toString();

virtual double computeArea(){return 2+3.0};

virtual bool isPointInShape(int,int);
virtual bool isPointOnShape(int,int);



private:
string name;
bool containsWarpSpace;


};
```

**Class Square**

```
   #include "ShapeTwoD.h"
  class Square:public ShapeTwoD
 {
 public:
 virtual double computeArea(){return 2+4.0};

 };
```

In my main method , i am trying to call the Square versions of the method computeArea() instead i keep calling ShapeTwoD version of the method computeArea(). I read online that putting the keyword **virtual** would allow the method to be determined dynamically hence allowing me to call the Square version of the method computeArea()

Why is this happening and how do i call the Square versions of the method computeArea()

```
 using namespace std;

 #include "Square.h"

 int main()
 {

  Square s;
  s.setName("Sponge");
  cout<<s.computeArea(); //outputs 5 when i expect it to output 6
 }
```

Comment: Your must have removed the problem in producing your sample code. This [should output 6](http://ideone.com/aBuRid) after trivial fixes.

Comment: Even without virtual, an instance of `Square` would call the `computeArea` function in `Square`.  I agree this is not the actual code you're having an issue with.

Comment: does it matter if i am only including the headers file of the class Square to the main method , please see edits

Comment: That shouldn't matter. `Square.h` includes `Shape2D.h` anyway.

Comment: If the includes are messed up, then it wouldn't compile.

Comment: For some unknown reason , it works now . Whats the point of virtual function if it works without the virtual function

Comment: even with your edits, this code doesn't compile.  Consider whittling it down to the code you're worried about and testing that.  And please post code that at least compiles unless you're asking about compiler errors.

Comment: @Computernerd - well, unless you post the actual code that's working, it's going to remain unknown!

Comment: The point is that you use `polymorphism`, which you are not, because you are acting directly on a `Square` instance. Try doing the work in a function `void doStuff(ShapeTwoD& shape);` and you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work and return `6` as expected for me:

```
class ShapeTwoD {
public:
    virtual double computeArea(){return 2+3.0;};
};

class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{
public:
    virtual double computeArea(){return 2+4.0;};    
};
```

I had to add `;` before `}` in both `computeArea`, did you miss just in the example? Else maybe you are not running the latest build.

**edit**

The include doesn't matter, as the files are included as if they are coded where you include them.

If you are using `gcc/g++` (but I guess other compilers have similar option) you can use the option `-E` to see how the `.c/.cpp` file result after the pre-compilation phase (also `#include`)

`g++ -c -E test.cpp`

There's the result:

```
# 2 "test.cpp" 2

using namespace std;

# 1 "square.h" 1
# 1 "shapetwo.h" 1
class ShapeTwoD
{
public:
 virtual double computeArea(){return 2+3.0;};
};
# 2 "square.h" 2

class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{
public:
 virtual double computeArea(){return 2+4.0;};
};
# 6 "test.cpp" 2

int main() {
 Square s;
 cout<<s.computeArea();
}
```

Comment: Works for me too - I even put up the working code on codepad:  http://codepad.org/p5PaiKHh

Comment: i think it has something to do with the fact that i am including the header files of the different classes only